Segmentation fault during TCP connection
I have written a function that connects to a TCP server, sends a string, and receives a string reply. There is also a buffer defined as a char array, that every time gets cleared and filled with string reply from socket.
This function is called simultaneously by multiple pthreads in my program. The problem is that it works fine but after a couple of minutes, program crashes with signal 11 (SIGSEGV).
I'm not an expert cpp developer, Can you help me with this?
Also, if there is a better implementation, I would be appreciated if you share that.
    int software::send_tcp_remote_cmd(std::string inputstr, std::string *outputstr, short timeout)
{
    int port = config["common"]["rch_port"].get<int>();
    // create a message buffer
    char msg[4096] = {'\0'};
    // setup a socket and connection tools
    struct hostent *host = gethostbyname(config["common"]["rch_ip"].get<std::string>().c_str());
    sockaddr_in sendSockAddr;
    bzero((char *)&sendSockAddr, sizeof(sendSockAddr));
    sendSockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sendSockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr =
        inet_addr(inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr *)*host->h_addr_list));
    sendSockAddr.sin_port = htons(port);
    int clientSd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    struct timeval tv;
    tv.tv_sec = timeout;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;
    setsockopt(clientSd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (const char *)&tv, sizeof tv);
    // try to connect...
    cout << "send_tcp_remote_cmd: Connecting" << endl;
    int status = connect(clientSd,
                         (sockaddr *)&sendSockAddr, sizeof(sendSockAddr));
    if (status < 0)
    {
        cout << "send_tcp_remote_cmd : Error connecting to socket!" << endl;
        close(clientSd);
        return -1;
    }
    cout << "send_tcp_remote_cmd: Connected to the server!" << endl;
    int bytesRead = 0;
    int bytesWritten = 0;
   spdlog::get("debug")->debug(">>>>>>>>TCP sending : {}", inputstr);
    if ((bytesWritten = send(clientSd, inputstr.c_str(), inputstr.size(), 0)) < 0)
    {
        cout << "send_tcp_remote_cmd : Error Send failed!" << endl;
        perror("Send failed");
        close(clientSd);
        return -1;
    }
    cout << "send_tcp_remote_cmd: Sent" << endl;
   spdlog::get("debug")->debug("Awaiting server response...");
    cout << "send_tcp_remote_cmd: Connected to the server!" << endl;
    bytesRead += recv(clientSd, msg, sizeof(msg) - 1, 0);
        cout << "send_tcp_remote_cmd: received-> " << bytesRead<<" bytes"<<endl;
        msg[bytesRead] = '\0'; // Null-terminate the string
    if (bytesRead > 0 && outputstr !=NULL)
    {
        outputstr->append(msg);
       spdlog::get("debug")->debug("Server: {}", (*outputstr));
    }

   spdlog::get("debug")->debug("Bytes written: {} Bytes read: {}", bytesWritten, bytesRead);
    if(bytesRead == 0)
    {
        cout << "!!!send_tcp_remote_cmd : bytesRead == 0" << endl;
        close(clientSd);
        return 0;
    }
    if (bytesRead == -1) {
       cout << "!!!send_tcp_remote_cmd : bytesRead == -1" << endl; 
    switch (errno) {
        case EAGAIN:
          perror("Failed to read from socket: code = EAGAIN");
          close(clientSd);
          break;
        default:
          perror("Failed to read from socket");
          close(clientSd);
          break;
    }
    return -2;
}
    close(clientSd);
    return 0;
}

Here is the stack trace:
--- command='' signal=11 date='29/08/2024 16:45:10' ---
    ./backend(+0x115207) [0x561998dcb207]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x3ef10) [0x7f4530a03f10]
    ./backend(_ZN7backend8software19send_tcp_remote_cmdENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEPS6_s+0x10b) [0x561998fa2abb]
    ./backend(_ZN7backend8software20get_disk_utilizationENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE+0x125) [0x561998fa5be5]
    ./backend(+0x18053e) [0x561998e3653e]
    ./backend(_ZN7httplib6Server7routingERNS_7RequestERNS_8ResponseERNS_6StreamE+0x580) [0x561998e171d0]
    ./backend(_ZN7httplib6Server15process_requestERNS_6StreamEbRbRKSt8functionIFvRNS_7RequestEEE+0xac2) [0x561998e18762]
    ./backend(_ZN7httplib9SSLServer24process_and_close_socketEi+0x49b) [0x561998e191db]
    ./backend(_ZNSt6thread11_State_implINS_8_InvokerISt5tupleIJN7httplib10ThreadPool6workerEEEEEE6_M_runEv+0x150) [0x561998ebba10]
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0xe067f) [0x7f453145767f]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x76db) [0x7f453262c6db]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x3f) [0x7f4530ae661f]

I thought it might cause by improper memset(), but it wasn't.
Edited: I edited the code and removed the unnecessary  memset() and increased buffer size. The server side buffer is char buff[3500], But the crash still happens in recv() as far as I noticed.

Compile your program with debug symbols (-g option in gcc) and run it again with a debugger to get a better stacktrace. You can also run it with valgrind that will detect invalid reads/writes that might be the source of your problem.

Since you mentioned multithreading, valgrind --tool=helgrind might also be useful for you.

char *serverIp = (char *)...c_str() - That's already a red flag on the second line of code. You're casting away const with a C cast. And in general this code is pretty bad. msg is zeroed twice, both of which are useless, before an unchecked and unnecessary strcpy is done. At that point, I stopped checking further. Given the quality of this code, a segmentation fault is not a surprise.

So many things that are of "C" and "C++" ...  For example your buffer a std::array<std::uint8_t,3500> msg{} would already get rid of one memset (when you see memset in C++ you missed something that could have been done more easily). struct hostent *host is also "C" syntax... not C++.  So really where have you been learning C++ from (it must have been a source that mostly taught you "C").

@MSalters Thanks for your reply. Can you give me a currect sample code for this?

@Rasoul.A: If you would hire me, I still wouldn't start on fixing the code. Instead, I look for the root causes. How did this code get written in the first place? Who wrote this and why? Is the hiring process working? Are developers receiving training after they're hired? How much more code like this is there?

@MSalters "You're casting away const with a C cast" - that same line is also causing serverIp to be a dangling pointer if get<std::string>() returns a temp string by value and not by reference. I stopped looking at that point.

@Msalters This code is part of a backend written in cpp using httplib and nlohmann json library. The only developer is me and I’m new to cpp and eager to learn. Could you give me any suggestions and some resources to learn and code better? Thanks.

@PepijnKramer If we want to work with sockets in cpp with should use c syntax like struct hostent *host. What is the problem with that exactly?

@Rasoul.A Not an exact problem, but just not necessary in C++. In general I just try to avoid having to interact with with legacy "C" api's like this socket library directly and have an adapter layer in between. Or for sockets I just use a C++ library directly, like boost::asio

Note for interprocess communication I no longer rely on sockets either but use something like protobuf/gRPC. One of the reasons is that if you send structs as bytes and cast them back at the receiving end. Both client and server need to be compiled 1) with the same compiler 2) with the same compiler settings 3) the source and target machine bus-width's must match (16/32/64 bits). 4) endianness must match. So using raw sockets is too fragile imo.  Just read this even if you're not going to use it : https://grpc.io/docs/languages/cpp/basics/

So, what if inputstr length is equal or longer than magical 3500 (size of msg)?
strcpy(msg, inputstr.c_str());

You write over random memory (local stack, this can be invisible for a long time).
And what if received data are exactly equal to magical 3500 (sizeof(msg))?
bytesRead += recv(clientSd, (char *)&msg, sizeof(msg), 0);

The sentinel \0 at the end of msg is wiped out. So while copying into std::string functionclone segfaults.

Thanks for your reply. Can you give me a currect sample code for this?
